# Is there a way to automate the creation of Windows workspace images in an IAC way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I can't seem to find any info on the management of Workspace images. We basically need a way to manage/build images if all of our AWS accounts were to disappear one day, we should be able to deploy code that rebuilds them based on a source image managed by AWS.

we can't be remoting into workspaces in order to install software & create these images.